# SQLite trigger to update Summary Counts

Tags: sqlite

Consider the following two (hypothetical) tables

Temperature

```
* day
* time
* lake_name
* station
* temperature_f
```

Temperature_summary

```
* day
* lake_name
* station
* count_readings_over_75f
* count_readings_below_75f
```

How can I write an **SQLite** Trigger to update the temperature_summary table on insert.  I want to increment the count.

Thank You,
Jeff

Comment: how is this related to ruby? are you looking for sql only implementation or in your ruby application?

Comment: Oops.  Its kinda habit to tag my questions as ruby.  I use it a lot.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This assumes you have already created the record for the day/lake_name/station before inserting temperatures on that day. Of course, you could add another trigger to do that.

```
create trigger Temperature_count_insert_trigger_hi after insert on Temperature
  when new.temperature_f >= 75
  begin
    update Temperature_summary set count_readings_over_75f = count_readings_over_75f + 1
    where new.day = day and new.lake_name = lake_name and new.station = station;
  end;

create trigger Temperature_count_insert_trigger_lo after insert on Temperature
  when new.temperature_f < 75
  begin
    update Temperature_summary set count_readings_below_75f = count_readings_below_75f + 1
    where new.day = day and new.lake_name = lake_name and new.station = station;
  end;
```

You can combine these into one slightly more complex trigger

```
create trigger Temperature_count_insert_trigger after insert on Temperature
  begin
    update Temperature_summary
    set count_readings_below_75f = count_readings_below_75f + (new.temperature_f < 75),
      count_readings_over_75f = count_readings_over_75f + (new.temperature_f >= 75)
    where new.day = day and new.lake_name = lake_name and new.station = station;
  end;
```

To insure that there is a row in Temperature_summary to update (a) make a unique index on Temperature_summary's `(day, lake_name, station)`, or make those columns the primary key, and (b)  do an insert or ignore in the trigger like so:

```
create trigger Temperature_count_insert_trigger after insert on Temperature
  begin
    insert or ignore into Temperature_summary
      values (new.day, new.lake_name, new.station, 0, 0);
    update Temperature_summary
    set count_readings_below_75f = count_readings_below_75f + (new.temperature_f < 75),
      count_readings_over_75f = count_readings_over_75f + (new.temperature_f >= 75)
    where new.day = day and new.lake_name = lake_name and new.station = station;
  end;
```

Comment: How do I handle the temperature_f <= 75, do I add another trigger or can I add another when statement.

Thanks!

Comment: The second option above handles both cases (above and below) in one trigger.

Comment: This assumes I have a record to update, what if I don't have a record to update.  I will need to order the triggers and do an insert?  Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a unique index on day, lake_name, station, or make those columns the primary key, then you could do an insert or ignore in the trigger. I've added that as a third example.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger can be created to update the counters in a single trigger. This will arguably improve performance and collect the related items into a single location.

```
create trigger Temperature_count_insert_trigger_lo after insert on Temperature    begin 
    update Temperature_summary set Temperature_summary set count_readings_over_75f = count_readings_over_75f + (new.temperature_f >= 75 ), count_readings_below_75f = count_readings_below_75f + (new.temperature_f < 75)
    where new.day = day and new.lake_name = lake_name and new.station = station;    end;
```

It may be necessary to include trigger processing for updates in the Temperature table if these can occur.